# How to become PayPal's 3rd party which paypal users can grant API access to

Tags: paypal

I am creating a client software to help online sellers analyzing their `paypal` transactions, one step needs to be done before user can use this software is that they need to grant `paypal api access` to my software in the page shown below:
[image]

However I am not a `paypal` 3rd party provider, so my question is how can I apply this role?

I searched `developer.paypal.com` but didn't find any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give permission to any third party(such as you want to give API permissions to your developer), then your third party(developer) needs to create a PayPal account and request the API credentials(by logging to his/her paypal account)
In order to give permission to your third party, you need to enter the third party(developer) API username(API username of the developer) to give permissions.